# How to get all metric's labels and values in Wavefront?

Tags: wavefront-telegraf

In Wavefront I have a metric `jvm.memory.max.bytes.gauge`. I need to implement filtering on time series but I don't know the exact label name neither the exact value.

Is there a way to see all labels and their values in Wavefront of a metric?

Answer (score 0):

In `Browse Metric` menu in Wavefront we can  select the metric and than export it to `csv`. In that `csv` there are all labels.

In popup window on the graph we can scroll vertically <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.